# JavaScript GET request

Tags: javascript, json, base64

I'm new to JS, I don't have a lot of experience, I would like to ask for help, I want to do a post to the address, and bring out a photo that I will get in reply in base64.
I tried that way, but it did not work

```html
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();

Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  console.log(Http.responseText)
}
```

My answer

```html
{
"snaphot" : string base64
}
```

Comment: Look for Ajax examples.

Comment: It looks like it actually worked. You're probably not sending the expected answer in the backend side.

Comment: @JordiNebot And can you show me an example, or help me write a base64 response to some variable?)))

Comment: Well, that would depend on the programming language you're using in the backend. I'm sure you can Google it.